# cpp custom std allocator

Tags: c++, allocator

First timer with allocator.
I am really struggling with a custom allocator.
I would say its obvious I don't know what I'm doing here.
My goal is to put all of the memory for the object in the process's heap.

I want the allocation to come from the system so its not language / runtime dependent.
I don't really want a struct, I just want:

```
std::list< WCHAR[SIZE], TestAllocator<WCHAR[SIZE]>> list;
```

or, I'd allocate the memory outside of the list and then just store a pointer to it

```
std::list< void*, TestAllocator<void*>> list;
```

But I don't see how to do it with non struct / classes.  So I have a struct.
This thing crashes all over the place.
The code below that instantiates the list crashes, it doesn't even have to get to a list item creation / insert.

The allocator is used for the list creation before I attempt to add an item. (which I don't understand.)  It seems to me that the allocator should only be used for the struct type I'm trying to add to the list.  If the allocator is used to create the list and the items it holds how do I create the memory for the 2 different types, the list type and the list entry type?

Some other observations / questions.
When my list is created, it is placed at the memory address created:

OSAllocator::allocate count:[1] bytes each:[8][0x8] bytes total:[8][0x8]addr:[4305640][**0x41B2E8**]
OSAllocator::construct placement new:[4305640][**0x41B2E8**] sizeof(val):[8][0x8]

However, when my entry is created, it is placed 2 bytes past the address created:

OSAllocator::allocate count:[1] bytes each:[8200][0x2008] bytes total:[8200][0x2008] addr:[8837144][**0x86D818**]
OSAllocator::construct placement new:[8837152][**0x86D820**] sizeof(val):[8192][0x2000]

Is there an explanation for that?

Please help point out what I'm missing.

Thanks.

```
// allocator...

pointer allocate(size_type size, TestAllocator<void>::const_pointer hint = 0)
{
    pointer p = (pointer)::HeapAlloc(   ::GetProcessHeap(),
                                HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY | HEAP_NO_SERIALIZE, 
                                size*sizeof(T) );
    gCountAllocate++;
    if( OSAllocatorConsole )
        wprintf( L"OSAllocator::allocate:             [%u][0x%X]\n", p, p );

    return p;
}   
size_type max_size() const throw() {return size_t(-1) / sizeof(value_type);}
void construct(pointer p, const T& val)
{
    gCountConstructPlaceNew++;
    if( OSAllocatorConsole )
        wprintf( L"OSAllocator::construct placement new:[%u][0x%X]\n", p, p );

    ::CopyMemory( p, &val, sizeof(val) );
}

typedef struct _LogLine
{
    WCHAR _logLine[4*1024];
} LOGLINE, *PLOGLINE;

DWORD TestAllocatorChar(int argc, WCHAR* argv[])
{
    WCHAR buf[32] = {0};
    DWORD total = 1;
    std::list< LOGLINE, TestAllocator<LOGLINE>> list;

    PLOGLINE pll = NULL;
    LOGLINE ll = {0};

    for(int i=0; i<total; i++ )
    {
        ::StringCchPrintfW( ll._logLine, 4*1024, L"count:[%u]", i );

        list.push_back( ll );
    }

    for( int i=0; i<total; i++ )
    {
        //pll = list.front();
        wprintf( L"%s\n", list.front()._logLine );

        wprintf( L"HeapFree item:[%u]\n", i );
        //::HeapFree( ::GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_NO_SERIALIZE, p );
        list.pop_front();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you feel the need for a custom allocator at all. Where, other than the "process' heap", would it be allocated by default?

Comment: Have you read through [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4795/C-Standard-Allocator-An-Introduction-and-Implement)?

Comment: C++ code to allocate a pointer on the heap: `char *x = new char[1024];` (the default std::allocator allocates on the heap already).

Comment: I've got a logging mechanism that is getting some memory allocated in 1 dll and some in another, all are queued to a thread and later logged and then deleted.  The new's in dll x don't appear to allow the frees from dll y, so there are those crt crashes.  I have a way to fix that, but in that process I wanted to entertain / learn from this as a possible solution.  Making all use the same memory allocation.  I did read through that code project article.

Comment: If those are ordinary inproc DLLs I don't see why you can't delete from anywhere. Is there some outproc tomfoolery going on?

Comment: flow is like this: native c exe has logger > COM > .net calls logger via ptr passed in.  when the messages from the .net logger are freed, it blows up.